# Отловить событие нажатия клавиши ввод

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, javascript

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые форумчане.
Подскажите, с таким вопросом, пожалуйста.
Есть страница сайта (содержит кое-какую информацию и несколько полей для заполнения с кнопкой (сделаны не как форма), при нажатии на которую отправляется ajax-запрос. Вопрос в том, что необходимо отловить нажатие клавиши ввод, по результату которого также будет вызываться ajax-запрос.
Кое-как отловить получается нажатие ввода, когда какое-нибудь поле находиться в фокусе (правда тогда в поле ничего другого вводить нельзя), а чтобы в фокусе поля не были, то, что бы я не делал, не получается(
Подскажите, как и что сделать?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('html').keydown(function(e){ //отлавливаем нажатие клавиш
  if (e.keyCode == 13) { //если нажали Enter, то true
    alert("Ура нажали Enter");
  }
});
```